# How to save string as binary file

Tags: c++

Heres my code

```
    bool saveFile (string name, string contents)
{
    ofstream file;
    file.open(name.c_str(), ios::binary);
    file.write(contents.c_str(),contents.size());
    file.close();

}
```

Ok edit:

My string contains

> 10100101111111110000

When I save it as binary file and open using notepad I expect to see random characters from ascii table but instead I see exact same stream of 0s and 1s

Comment: What exactly do you expect to have in the file, and what do you actually get?

Comment: I want to save compressed file and it saves as text so its actually bigger than before compresion.

Comment: That doesn't answer my question at all. Show an example at least.

Comment: @zarcel What sort of compression? You said you have a string of 1's and 0's. You should show us what you have and what you expect. Literally.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have a "binary" text string of `'1'` and `'0'` characters, you can encode it into bytes using `std::bitset<8>`.

```
void saveFile (std::string name, std::string contents) {
    std::ofstream file(name.c_str(), std::ios::binary);
    for ( std::size_t byte = 0; byte < contents.size(); byte += 8 ) {
        file.put( std::bitset< 8 >( contents, byte, // convert one byte
          std::min( (std::size_t) 8, contents.size() - byte ) // or as many bits as are left
          .to_ulong() ); // to two's complement representation
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you edit this to not refer to 'binary strings' as I do not think given the context of the question it is very clear exactly what this means.

Comment: @thecoshman Clarified what that meant… he mentioned something like this in a comment. Ah, and now he updated the question to say the same.

Comment: I am getting this error. Is it my outdated mingw or ur code?
 no matching function for call to `min(int, unsigned int)'

Comment: @zarcel Sorry, here's a fix.

Answer (score 1):

Roughly speaking the main difference between a binary and a text file is that every byte you write to the first is saved unchanged, while a newline character written to the second may be translated to the underlying system's newline sequence, e.g. carriage return + line feed for Windows.

Here is an example:

```
#include <fstream>
#include <ios>

int main() {
  std::ofstream file;
  std::string s = "Hello, World!\n";
//  file.open("binary", std::ios_base::binary);
  file.open("text");
  file.write(s.c_str(),s.size());
  file.close();
}
```

If I compile this program as it is now with g++ and run it on Windows I get this output:

```
$ od -c text
0000000   H   e   l   l   o   ,       W   o   r   l   d   !  \r  \n
0000017
```

If I comment the line where the "text" file is written and uncomment the one where the "binary" file is written I get:

```
$ od -c binary
0000000   H   e   l   l   o   ,       W   o   r   l   d   !  \n
0000016
```

(`od` is a command from UNIX/Linux that display the exact contents of a file)

Now, as to actually answer your question, here is an example on how you could do it "by hand". Using a `bitset`, as in the accepted answer, is probably a more sensible approach:

```
#include <fstream>
#include <ios>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

int main() {
    std::string s = "10100101111111110000";
    std::vector<unsigned char> v;
    unsigned char c = 0;
    int i = 0;
    for ( auto d : s ) {
        if ( d == '1' )
            ++c;
        c <<= 1;
        ++i;
        if ( i % 8 == 0 ) {
            v.push_back(c);
            c = 0;
            i = 0;
        }
    }
    if ( i != 0 ) {
        c <<= 8 - i;
        v.push_back(c);
    }
    std::basic_ofstream<unsigned char> file;
    file.open("binary", std::ios_base::binary);
    file.write(v.data(), v.size());
    file.close();
}
```

Comment: what? I think you need to explain this better.

Comment: Talk more about how you open the file, and less about what the file is.

Answer (score 1):

You wrote readable characters (representing the digit characters '1' and '0') to the binary file, so when you look at it in an editor you can read it.  If you want to read "garbage" you need to write "garbage" -- "unreadable" characters to the file that are outside of the range of "printable" characters (`a-zA-Z0-9!@#$%^`, etc.).

Comment: you have missed the point of this question

Comment: I have not missed any point, I have explained the reason for the observed behavior.  When printable characters are stored to a file, they do not "change into garbage" just because the file type is binary.   The OP needs to understand this and that will lead to his ultimate goal.

Comment: Hi, I don't want to read garbage. My point is when I save my string it is supposed to be binary representation of ascii thus compressed file(its huffman coding). But since it is readable its actually bigger.

Comment: Understood.   But it's important to start with the understanding of what happens when you store a character (which takes 1 byte, 8 bits of space [in the ASCII encoding]) to a file, and when you inspect a file with a text editor or print it to the console.   The '1' character already has a binary encoding based on ASCII (or unicode, etc.).   So when you store the character '1' to a file, you're getting 8 (maybe 16 for wide characters/unicode) bits, not just 1 bit.

Comment: In order to store a particular bit pattern, you need to create a memory image of the bit pattern (in chars, int, etc.) in a chunk of memory (either scalar variables, or an array), and store that data structure to the binary file.   Then when you read the file back in a text editor, or list it to the console, you should see your bit pattern interpreted as a string of characters, according to the character encoding your editor/console uses.